# How do I find a Form from another class in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I have the following aspx page that has a series of dropdown boxes to get parameters, and a series of iFrames that calls loads individual charts based on the parameters.  The body of the page looks like this:

```
<body>
<form id="bmBehaviorForm" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
        <div runat="server">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddSchoolYear" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddValueChanged" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="ddSchoolType" UseButtons="true" UseSelectAllNode="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddValueChanged" runat="server">
                <Style2 DropDownBoxBoxWidth="200" SelectBoxCssClass="selectHeight" />
                <Texts SelectBoxCaption="School Type" />
            </asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>
            <asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="ddSchools" UseButtons="true" UseSelectAllNode="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddValueChanged" runat="server">
                <Style2 DropDownBoxBoxWidth="350" SelectBoxCssClass="selectHeight" />
                <Texts SelectBoxCaption="Schools" />
            </asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>
            <asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="ddGrades" UseButtons="true" UseSelectAllNode="true" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Vertical" 
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddValueChanged" runat="server">
                <Style2 DropDownBoxBoxWidth="150" SelectBoxCssClass="selectHeight" />
                <Texts SelectBoxCaption="Grades" />
            </asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>
            <asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="ddEvent" UseButtons="true" UseSelectAllNode="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddValueChanged" runat="server">
                <Style2 DropDownBoxBoxWidth="400" DropDownBoxBoxHeight="5000" SelectBoxCssClass="selectHeight" />
                <Texts SelectBoxCaption="Behavior Events" />
            </asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>
            <asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="ddResolution" UseButtons="true" UseSelectAllNode="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddValueChanged" runat="server">
                <Style2 DropDownBoxBoxWidth="400" DropDownBoxBoxHeight="5000" SelectBoxCssClass="selectHeight" />
                <Texts SelectBoxCaption="Resolutions" />
            </asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row rowPaddingTop">
        <iframe name="iName_iSchools" id="iSchools" style="border: none;" width="775px" height="500px" 
            src="behaviorbySchool.aspx"></iframe>
        <iframe name="iName_iGrades" id="IGrades" style="border: none;" width="775px" height="350px"
            src="behaviorbyGrade.aspx"></iframe>
        <iframe name="iName_iMonths" id="IMonths" style="border: none;" width="775px" height="350px"
            src="behaviorbyMonth.aspx"></iframe>
        <iframe name="iName_iLocations" id="ILocations" style="border: none;" width="775px" height="350px"
            src="behaviorbyLocation.aspx"></iframe>
        <iframe name="iName_iDemographicsYTD" id="IDemographicsYTD" style="border: none;" width="800px" height="400px"
            src="behaviorbyDemographics.aspx?ytd=1"></iframe>
        <iframe name="iName_iDemographicsMTH" id="IDemographicsMTH" style="border: none;" width="800px" height="400px"
            src="behaviorbyDemographics.aspx?ytd=0"></iframe>
    </div>
</form>
```

Inside the codebehind for each of the iFrames, I would like to reference the dropdown boxes from the calling form to get the selected values.  I've been trying various forms of the code below, but my syntax isn't correct. How can I do this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DMC.BM
{
    public partial class behaviorBySchool : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        refData rd = new refData();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form1 frm = (form1)FindControl("bmBehaviorForm");
         }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
After getting these awesome answers and clarifications below, I think what I'm going to do is replace the iFrames with javascript to construct my graphs. I'm using Highcharts but have recently discovered dotnet Highcharts -- the dotnet Highcharts is what I was building in each iFrame.  I think I'm going to abandon that and just build my charts with the base Highcharts from javascript, which will take care of all my problems.

Comment: Can't be done. There is no relationship between a page and IFrames it contains server-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instances of these forms do not exist on the server at the same time. Even if they did, there is no connection between them.

Put any data, that `iframe` forms require, in the query string part of their urls that you assign to `iframe.src` attributes. Then you will be able to access these data in `iframe` pages' C# code as `Request["ytd"]`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do isn't possible. At least with the way you currently have it. ASP.NET has no clue what is in your iframe. An iframe is a purely client side idea.

Do you *REALLY* want to have iframes, or are you trying to simply have reusable bits of code/content that you can access from the code behind? If the latter (which is almost certainly what you want), you should take your .aspx pages and make them into ASP.Net UserControls. After you do that, THEN you can access those controls the way I think you want to.

Comment: I'm definitely not married to iFrames...this page is going to be loading 6 graphs and depending on the parameters selected, some of them could take a little bit longer to load than I'd like. iFrames seemed to be the best solution to let the faster graphs load sooner to give the impression that it wasn't slow. If I can do that with user controls, then I will definitely take a look at using them instead.